# Capturing Audio from Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, c++, audio

I'm working in C#/C++ in Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 10 at the moment. I am working on a hijacker style app that traps and captures audio from a number of different applications. I have successfully captured audio from Chrome, Firefox and IE. I can also capture audio from Universal Apps which work quite differently.

I am able to hijack Microsoft Edge, but unable to capture Audio under any of my regular methods. Can anyone point me to any information about how Edge works with the Windows Audio system?

Comment: To capture the audio manually I'd click to [show disabled recording devices, showing the mixer, then enable that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fdnx.png), then I'd capture it in Audacity.

Comment: Thanks, I need to do this in code.